# Find regular polygon's vertices

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, geometry, polygon

I have some properties defined by the user, and then I want use them to automatically generate a regular polygon. The properties are centre x, centre y, radius and number of vertices. I would like to know how to calculate the x and y coordinates of all vertices of a regular polygon. I've already tried to do as [Calculate coordinates of a regular polygon's vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436453/calculate-coordinates-of-a-regular-polygons-vertices) discussion. But it always gives me thw wrong coordinates. My current code is as follows (C++):

```
#define DOUBLE(a) ((a)*(a))
```

...

```
if(radius <= 0 || vertices < 3)
  return NULL;

Polygon* poly = new Polygon;

double angle = DOUBLE(M_PI) / vertices;

for(long i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
{
  double a = (angle * i);

  poly->add(centerX + radius * cos(a), centerY + radius * sin(a));
}

return poly;
```

Comment: You also need the angle of the first vertex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an error in your angle calculation.

The angle between each vertex should be `2 * M_PI / vertices`.

Obviously your macro:

```
#define DOUBLE(a) ((a)*(a))
```

is incorrect.

However in C++ you really shouldn't use macros for such trivial operations anyway - it should at the very most be an *inline* function, or just the direct formula given above.

Comment: That was it, I think I'm going crazy

Comment: @belisarius Okay, It's just 'cause I'm new as user.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#define DOUBLE(a) ((a) + (a))
```

or

```
#define DOUBLE(a) (2 * (a))
```

You are defining SQUARE(a) under a false identity.